# Kafka log retention time per topic in server.properties

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to lower the retention period for one of the Kafka topics. I want the rest of the topics to still use the default retention time (7 days).
I know that we can set this through terminal: `bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper XXX --alter --topic XXXX --config retention.ms=86400000`.
I was wondering if there is a way to do this so that it is set in `server.properties` and can be used in the future. For example, for the default retention time, we have `log.retention.minutes = XXX`.

EDIT: after some research, I noticed that per-topic configurations should better be done this way in ZK (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-554). But I'm still wondering if I can do this programmatically rather than using `kafka-topics.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want some topics to have a different retention time, I'm afraid you will have to specify it when creating them using `kafka-topics.sh`.

In `server.properties` you can only specify configurations that apply to all topics that don't have overrides.

Comment: I think I should be able to alter it using something like `bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper XXX --alter --topic XXXX --config retention.ms=86400000`. Is this the only way to set overrides?

Comment: If the topic already exists, yes use this command to alter it. You can also specify overrides when creating topics

Answer (score 1):

Using https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html you can create your own programmatic solution but I don't believe there's any sort of Kafka configuration that'd do it for you. You could also use a tool like https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager.